# Get Finer Grid with respect to x using NDSolve in Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-value

[image]

I use Mathematica NDSolve to numerically solve V(x,t) and export the numerical values of V(x,t) at each x and t into an external csv file. I find Mathematica only numerically give results with step size of 1 in both x and t. However, I want a finer grid of the numerical results, for example, 0, 0.01, 0.02, … , M in the x-dimension. I tried to add MaxStepSize→0.1 in the NDSolver, but it gives errors and seems not solving finer grid of x in the csv file. 
NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 95.86748044587323`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected. >>

**My question: what is the correct way to get numerical matrix on V(x,t) on a finer x? The relevant code is in export.nb**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're exporting the `data1` table to your spreadsheet, so that's where you'll need to request the additional sample points. Something like this should work:

```
data1=Table[Evaluate[v[t,x]/.s],{t,0,T},{x,0,M,0.1}]
```

The fourth argument of the iterator term is the step size, which defaults to 1, so you'll need to make it smaller if you want the intermediate points.

Comment: It works! Thanks so much!